# About dbus-daemon's activation parameter

Tags: 12.04, upstart, dbus

I'm using `Ubuntu12.04 LTS`.

I saw following line in `/etc/init.d/dbus.conf`.

```
exec dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
```

And I saw the man page for `dbus-daemon`,

and then found the `--activation=systemd` parameter.

I tried to use `--activation=systemd` rather than `--activation=upstart`.

BTW, system is good with this parameter.

What differences are exist between the parameters(`--activation=systemd` and `--actication=upstart`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use one or the other.

Read more about [**Upstart**](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)
Read more about [**Systemd**](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)

> Upstart is an event-based replacement for the /sbin/init daemon which
>   handles starting of tasks and services during boot, stopping them
>   during shutdown and supervising them while the system is running.   It
>   was originally developed for the Ubuntu distribution, but is intended
>   to be suitable for deployment in all Linux distributions as a
>   replacement for the venerable System-V init.

With `--activation=upstart` your `dbus-daemon` will be activated with Upstart timings.
Otherwise your `systemd` (systemd is alternate boot manager) will calculate timings for your `dbus-daemon`.

Ubuntu uses **Upstart** years and years ago.
**Systemd** is default for these distributions: Fedora, Debian, openSUSE, Mageia, Gentoo.

Comment: What influences my system is suffered with --activation=systemd?

Comment: To use System-V init instead Upstart init. Upstart better for Ubuntu.

Comment: in other words only your preference will suffers )) just if you do not want to make from your Ubuntu some other distribution. So it will be "Debian" more than Ubuntu alike.